# How to initialise and create object of UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uistoryboard, viewcontroller

I want to create object of UITableViewController and want to pass values from ViewController to UITableViewController. But It gives error like "UITableViewController is not key-value coding-compliant for the key superclass."
I tried this but won't help:

```
[[MytableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MytableViewController_identifier"] bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

Comment: Had you set `MytableViewController_identifier` for your tableViewController in the identity inspector?

Comment: Yes, I already did it first then I created object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

```
MytableViewController *mtvc = (MytableViewController *)[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MytableViewController_identifier"];
```